# Matlab cftool erf fitting function

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to make a fitting operation using MATLAB cftool. The experimental dataset available describes an erf() function, and I need to know some parameters. 
The equation used is:

```
% equation: y0+(p0/2)*erf((sqrt(2)(x-x0))/w0)
```

and the fitting as you can see in the picture is perfect. What I don't understand is why the result that I get are incorrect.

[image]

[image]

Ideally should be something like y0=0.5, p0=1, x0=2700, w0=600.

By changing the starting points for these parameters, close to those that I expect, the model is totally wrong. I wondering what can be the problem.

Thanks for you help,

Pablo.

Comment: "where x is normalized by mean 2299 and std 1330" - so you need to find out how to denormalize it.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. There was a checkbox, center and scale X data, checked. By un-check that and also inserting the correct start points the fitting is working well and the parameters are correct.
Thanks for your answer thewaywewalk.